# Why does Windows state "Unverified Publisher" for signed executable with a subsequently expired certificate

Tags: windows, sign, authenticode

In 2014, I bought a class two code signing certificate from StartSSL which I used to digitally sign my binaries. This certificate has just expired and I actually am in the process of trying to get a new one. However, in an unrelated incident, I ran one of my signed setup programs in a VM and was somewhat ... annoyed ... when Windows brought up the "Unverified Publisher" variant of the UAC dialog.

When I view the digital signature properties I see this:

[image: WTF]

Of course the certificate has expired, but why is the file (that was signed within the validity period) suddenly unverified? I haven't seen this happen with other software, for example if I look at an old signed copy of Office 2003 setup, that doesn't complain about an invalid signature and that validaty period expired a decade ago.

[image: Still valid]

Why is this? Frankly I'm now wondering what the the point of buying the certificate in the first place was and seriously considering cancelling the in-process replacement. Seems kind of pointless when they invalidate themselves. Or is this the different between class 2 and 3? (Class 3 is the version I'm trying to get hold of now)

Comment: Perhaps [this explains it?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/03/22/everything-you-need-to-know-about-authenticode-code-signing/)  "Update: Not all publisher certificates are enabled to permit timestamping to provide indefinite lifetime. If the publisher’s signing certificate contains the lifetime signer OID (OID_KP_LIFETIME_SIGNING 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13), the signature becomes invalid when the publisher’s signing certificate expires, even if the signature is timestamped."

Comment: Harry, thanks for that comment. That actually does seem to be the answer (The cert has the "Code Signing (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3)" and "Lifetime Signing (1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13)" Extended Key Usage flags, whilst an older Comodo cert I had doesn't have any "Extended" usage flags, and doesn't seem to have self expired). If you'd like to add this as an answer I can "mark" it, otherwise I'll add it myself with some screenshots. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is apparently a by-design limitation on some code-signing certificates, as described in the first footnote to Microsoft's blog post, [Everything you need to know about Authenticode Code Signing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/03/22/everything-you-need-to-know-about-authenticode-code-signing/):

> Not all publisher certificates are enabled to permit timestamping to provide indefinite lifetime. If the publisher’s signing certificate contains the lifetime signer OID (OID_KP_LIFETIME_SIGNING 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13), the signature becomes invalid when the publisher’s signing certificate expires, even if the signature is timestamped. This is to free a Certificate Authority from the burden of maintaining Revocation lists (CRL, OCSP) in perpetuity.

You may wish to check whether the replacement certificate will have the same limitation, and perhaps consider an alternative vendor.

Comment: I'd already decided not to go with StartSSL again as a vendor given their recent woes, and am currently in the process of obtaining a Comodo certificate (although not without qualms either, I originally had a Comodo cert in 2013 and it was a very disagreeable experience; as far as I am personally concerned they provide the most terrible service on the planet) and other providers are quite expensive. Even with certificates you seem to get what you pay for, I just wish I knew about this upfront, I wouldn't have bothered with StartSSL at all then. At least I know now however.

Comment: Comodo has become Sectigo, writing this in 2023, calling them from my experience gets someone on the phone immediately, no wait, with emailing on the other hand or submitting tickets I waited days, now I just call.